# Assistance with a popup box?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, popup

So, I literally have one more thing to do to finish my Calculator, which is make an error box popup if the textbox is empty. Currently, it shows a message, saying an error has occurred. I want it to simply launch a popup if the textbox is empty, and a "Continue" button to close the window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple popup, try this:

```
if textboxNum1.Text = "" OR textboxNum2.Text = "" Then
MsgBox("Textboxes are empty!")
else
'Enter process here
End if
```

Or try this:

```
if(textboxNum1.Text = "" OR textboxNum2.Text = "") Then
MsgBox("Textboxes are empty!")
else
'Enter process here
End if
```

Comment: That did not work. I should've mentioned I am new to Visual Basic. The "If" simply gets an error "Keyword is not valid as an identifier"

Comment: I should mention my calculator only has one text box, and the rest is all buttons. I wanted it to give a message if you tried to backspace while the box was empty.